# array to string concatenation

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

I got the next array:

```
    Array ( 

[0] => Array ( [email] => xasxxxxxx@yahoo.com [btc] => 0.00287896 [tn] => 6.615 [address] => 2BY4HM [status] => pending ) 

[1] => Array ( [email] => xxxxx@yahoo.com [btc] => 0.04000 [tokens_given] => 5 [address] => xxXXxxxxxaaaxxXs [status] => pending ) 

[2] => Array ( [email] => xsxxxx@yahoo.com [btc] => 0.04000 [tokens_given] => 5 [address] => xxXXxxxxxaaaxxXs [status] => pending ) 

[3] => Array ( [email] => xssasas5@yahoo.com [btc] => 0.04000 [tokens_given] => 5 [address] => xxXXxxxxxaaaxxXs [status] => pending ) 

[4] => Array ( [email] => xxxxxx@yahoo.com [btc] => 0.04000 [tokens_given] => 5 [address] => xxXXxxxxxaaaxxXs [status] => pending )

)
```

How am I supposed to get all 'address'es in a variable as a string separated by comma?

something like this

$string = "1stadress, 2ndaddress, 3ndadress' etc

I tried:

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", $row['address']); // where $ row is the array above
```

and it failed.

Comment: Using foreach loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
echo implode(',',array_column($myarray,'address'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop though array and collect the relevant members, I'd perefer using untermidiate array this way it can be reused if needed later

```
$buffer = [];
foreach($myArray as $id=>$data){
  $buffer[] = $data['address'];
}
$output = implode(',',$buffer);
```